# Smoothness of integrals of dirac delta function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I found this text online:

"In general, **integrating** the $\delta$ function or one of its integrals makes it *smoother*. **Differentiating**  it increases the discontinuities. For example $\int\delta $ is discontinuous itself. $\int \int \delta $ is continuous but with a discontinuous *first* derivative. $\int \int \int \delta$ is continuous, but with a discontinuous *second* derivative, etc..."

I agree that $\int\delta $ is certainly discontinuous since it equates to the Heaviside function. However I do not agree that $\int \int \delta $ is continuous since wouldn't this simply be the Ramp function ($\int H(x)$) And isn't the Ramp function also discontinuous at $x = 0$?

Comment: What is according to you the limit of the ramp function approaching it from negative and positive zero?

Comment: Zero, I would say

Comment: So what makes you say that it is discontinues?

Comment: Because there is a kink there...

Comment: I guess discontinuous necessarily means there is a jump with infinite slope?

Comment: The slope of the ramp function near zero would either be zero or one (not infinite), however I think you are confused between continues and smooth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30670/discussion-between-user32882-and-fibonatic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first integral is the Heaviside function. It's discontinuous at $0$ because the limits from the left and from the right are different ($0$ and $1$). One might explain the discontinuity by saying that one can't trace the graph without  lifting the pencil.

The second integral **is** continuous: you can trace this graph without lifting your pencil. The limit as $x\to 0$ is $0$, and it agrees with the value of the function there.

[image: ramp]

The fact that there is a corner at $0$ means something different: this function is not *differentiable* at $0$. (The slopes from the left and from the right don't match.)

And the third integral is differentiable:

[image: parabola]